# ZST Compression Error In LMDE5 (Debian 11) Breaks Apt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, installation, tar

I recently installed WeChat via the deepin-wine install method described below:

First, I ran this in terminal:
`wget -O- https://deepin-wine.i-m.dev/setup.sh | sh`

Then I used the Synaptic Package Manager install method...

rebooted, and bam....  WeChat is working perfectly fine

**Problem:**
After successfully installing WeChat (it uses Wine6 as its base), I get confronted with the error below when I run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` in terminal:

"zstd unrecognized compression" error, **NOTE:** the zstd is already installed on my system

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmd4c0 libminizip1 libmng1 libqt5concurrent5 libsasl2-modules-db
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsndio7.0:i386 libwebp6 libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux3
  libwebpmux3:i386 libxcb-keysyms1 p7zip p7zip-full
14 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,770 kB of archives.
After this operation, 70.7 kB disk space will be freed.
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-nhWY9Y/00-libsasl2-modules-db_2.
1.28+dfsg-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.z
st', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-nhWY9Y/00-libsasl2-modules-
db_2.1.28+dfsg-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-nhWY9Y/01-libsasl2-modules-db_2.
1.28+dfsg-6ubuntu2_i386.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zs
t', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-nhWY9Y/01-libsasl2-modules-
db_2.1.28+dfsg-6ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
(Reading database ... 377133 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../02-libwebp6_0.6.1.2-1+dde_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libwebp6:i386 (0.6.1-2.1) ...
Unpacking libwebp6:amd64 (0.6.1.2-1+dde) over (0.6.1-2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-libwebp6_0.6.1.2-1+dde_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libwebp6:i386 (0.6.1.2-1+dde) over (0.6.1-2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libmd4c0_0.4.8-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmd4c0:amd64 (0.4.8-1) over (0.4.7-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libminizip1_1.1.1-1+rebuild_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libminizip1:amd64 (1.1.1-1+rebuild) over (1.1-8+b1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libmng1_1.0.10.1-1+rebuild_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmng1:amd64 (1.0.10.1-1+rebuild) over (1.0.10+dfsg-3.1+b5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libqt5concurrent5_5.15.6.3-1+dde_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5concurrent5:amd64 (5.15.6.3-1+dde) over (5.15.2+dfsg-9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libsndio7.0_1.5.0-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libsndio7.0:i386 (1.5.0-3) over (1.5.0-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libwebpmux3_0.6.1.2-1+dde_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libwebpmux3:amd64 (0.6.1-2.1) ...
Unpacking libwebpmux3:i386 (0.6.1.2-1+dde) over (0.6.1-2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-libwebpmux3_0.6.1.2-1+dde_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebpmux3:amd64 (0.6.1.2-1+dde) over (0.6.1-2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-p7zip-full_16.02+dfsg.2-1+dde_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking p7zip-full (16.02+dfsg.2-1+dde) over (16.02+dfsg-8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-p7zip_16.02+dfsg.2-1+dde_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking p7zip (16.02+dfsg.2-1+dde) over (16.02+dfsg-8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-libxcb-keysyms1_0.4.0.1-1+rebuild_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-keysyms1:amd64 (0.4.0.1-1+rebuild) over (0.4.0-1+b2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-nhWY9Y/00-libsasl2-modules-db_2.1.28+dfsg-6ubuntu2_amd64.
deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-nhWY9Y/01-libsasl2-modules-db_2.1.28+dfsg-6ubuntu2_i386.d
eb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas?